# Two Substitutions as Arguments

Tags: string, haskell, substitution

I'm writing a Haskell function that takes 2 substitutions as arguments. I've handled the case where if either of the arguments is `Nothing`, then the function will return `Nothing`. If neither one is `Nothing`, it should combine them into a single substitution. I've done the following:

```
args :: Maybe (Subst a) -> Maybe (Subst a) -> Maybe (Subst a)
args (Just v) (Just v') = Just (v ++ v')
args _        _         = Nothing
```

However, I'm receiving errors that the expected type doesn't match the actual type. I'm confused as to why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `++` is

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

but you're trying to apply it to two values of type `Subst a`.

You could write a helper function `combineSubs` like this:

```
combineSubs :: Subst a -> Subst a -> Subst a
combineSubs (S xs) (S ys) = S (xs ++ ys)
```

You can also pattern match on `S` in the arguments of your function `args`.

Comment: how would you suggest that I go about doing it using pattern matching

Comment: The basic idea here is that the arguments `v` and `v'` in your function `args` are values of type `Subst a`. Therefore, you can pattern match on these values by replacing the variables by according patterns. In the definition of `combineSubs` you can see how you can pattern match on a value of type `Subst a`.

Comment: @JanChristiansen So based off your example, I tried something like this (see edit above). But now I'm getting a pattern overlapping error

Comment: I believe your current error has to do with your line that says `args _ _ = Nothing`

Comment: Overlapping pattern means that there is a rule that never matches because the other patterns match all the cases. Therefore, your implementation should not cause an overlapping pattern warning and oddly for me ghc-7.4.1 does not report a warning.

Answer (score 2):

Just a remark to your architecture:

Is there really a difference between no substitution (which would be `Nothing` here) and an "empty" substituion `S []`? If not, you probably should drop the `Maybe` level and code missing substitutions simply as `S []`. If there *is* a difference, you might consider to add this case to `Subst`, e.g. `data Subst a = S [(String,a)] | None`.